# Tranformer Rule for Slideshow in Facebook Instant Article not working?

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I am using [Justified Gallery](https://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) and I want to publish my page as an Instant Article on Facebook. As I go through the documentations [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles), I found out that I can transform the images into [Slideshow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/slideshow) by [Transformer Rules](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/sdk/transformer-rules). Here is my gallery code:

```
<div class="myExMul">
     <a href="link_to_img" class="swipeboxImg">
         <img src="link_to_img" alt="example_text" class="myExMulImg">
     </a>
     <a href="link_to_img2" class="swipeboxImg">
         <img src="link_to_img2" alt="example_text2" class="myExMulImg">
     </a>
     <a href="link_to_img3" class="swipeboxImg">
         <img src="link_to_img3" alt="example_text3" class="myExMulImg">
     </a>
</div>
```

And here is my Transformer Rules:

```
{
   "class": "SlideshowRule",
   "selector": "div.myExMul",
},
{
    "class": "SlideshowImageRule",
    "selector": "img.myExMulImg",
    "properties": {
        "image.url": {
            "type": "string",
            "selector": "img.myExMulImg",
            "attribute": "src"
        },
        "caption.title": {
            "type": "string",
            "selector": "img.myExMulImg",
            "attribute": "alt"
        }
    }
}
```

When I imported the rules, it seems that my rules broke everything and I can no longer publish my articles, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So after some hours of research, I found the right rule for my code. The problem is you have to use the outer tag as the selector (in my case it's the `a` tag) instead of the inner tag (`img`).

```
{
   "class": "SlideshowRule",
   "selector": "div.myExMul"
},
{
    "class": "SlideshowImageRule",
    "selector": "a.swipeboxImg",
    "properties": {
        "image.url": {
            "type": "string",
            "selector": "img",
            "attribute": "src"
        },
        "caption.title": {
            "type": "string",
            "selector": "img",
            "attribute": "alt"
        }
    }
}
```